# C passing array of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This relates to C. I am having some trouble understanding how I can assign strings to char pointers within arrays from a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char* array[]);

int main(void)
{
    char* array[50];
    function(array);
    printf("array string 0: %s\n",array[0]);
    printf("array string 1: %s\n",array[1]);

}

void function(char* array[])
{
    char temp[] = "hello";
    array[0] = temp;
    array[1] = temp;

    return;
}
```

Ideally, I would like the main printf function to return

```
array string 0: hello
array string 1: hello
```

But I'm having trouble understanding arrays of pointers, how these pass to functions and how to manipulate them in the function. If I declare a string like `char temp[] = "string"` then how do I assign this to one of the main function `array[i]` pointers? (assuming I have my jargon right)

Comment: Use strcpy(char* dest, const char* source) to copy a string to another string (or char array).

Comment: Change `char temp[] = "hello";`  to be `char * temp = "hello";` and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char temp[] = "hello";` only creates a *local, temporary* array inside the function. So when the function exists, the array will be destroyed.

But with `array[0] = temp;` you're making `array[0]` point to the local array `temp`.

After the function returns, `temp` doesn't exist anymore. So accessing `array[0]` which pointed to `temp` will cause undefined behavior.

---

You could simply make `temp` static, so it also exists outside the function:

```
static char temp[] = "hello";
```

Or, you could *copy* the `"hello"` string to `array[0]` and `array[1]`. For copying C-strings, you normally use [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/).

```
char temp[] = "hello";
strcpy(array[0], temp);
strcpy(array[1], temp);
```

**However**, before copying you need to make sure `array[0]` and `array[1]` point to memory that has enough space to hold all characters of `"hello"`, including the terminating null character. So you have to do something like this before calling `strcpy`:

```
array[0] = malloc(6); 
array[1] = malloc(6);
```

(6 is the minimum numbers of characters that can hold `"hello"`.)

Comment: First allocate memory, then use strcpy().

Answer (score 1):

> how do I assign this to one of the main function array[i] pointers

1. Arrays cannot be assigned.
2. A pointer cannot hold an array, it can only refer to an array. For the latter the pointer needs to get an array's address assigned.

**Referring 1.**

This

```
char temp[] = "hello";
```

isn't an assigment, but an initialisation.

This

```
char temp[];
temp[] = "hello";
```

would not compile (the 2nd line errors), as an array cannot be assigned.

**Referring 2.**

This

```
char* array[50];
```

defines an array of 50 pointers to `char`, it could **reference** 50 `char`-arrays, that is 50 C-"strings". It cannot hold the C-"strings" themselfs.

**Example**

Applying what is mentioned above to your code whould lead to for example the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char* array[]);

int main(void)
{
  char* array[50];

  /* Make the 1st two elements point to valid memory. */
  array[0] = malloc(42); /* Real code shall test the outcome of malloc() 
                            as it might fail and very well return NULL! */
  array[1] = malloc(42); 
  function(array);
  printf("array string 0: %s\n",array[0]);
  printf("array string 1: %s\n",array[1]);

  return 0;
}


void function(char* array[])
{
  char temp[] = "hello";

  /* Copy the content of temp into the memory that was allocated to 
     the array's 1st memebrs in main(). */
  strcpy(array[0], temp);
  strcpy(array[1], temp);

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, you need to allocate the destination.

second, `char temp[] = "hello";` in function() is local variable. you cannot use their outside of the function. use `strcpy` to copy the content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char* dest)
{
    char temp[] = "hello";
    strcpy(dest, temp);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    // or just char dest[10] = {0};
    char *dest = malloc(10);

    function(dest);
    printf("dest: %s\n", dest);
}
```

In you program, you defined `char* array[50];`, so you need to create memory space for each item:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char* a[])
{
    char temp[] = "hello";
    strcpy(a[0], temp);
    strcpy(a[1], temp);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *a[50];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        a[i] = malloc(10);

    function(a);
    printf("a[0]: %s\n", a[0]);
    printf("a[1]: %s\n", a[1]);
}
```